# Populating JComboBox with XML attribute - DOM4J

Tags: java, xml, jcombobox, dom4j

I was trying to use DOM4J API to populate a JComboBox with a XML file attributes, but I don't know how it's done.

I've been reading the API documentation but I still can't do it.
Can you help me?

Here's a sample of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<components>
    <resources id="House">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
            <maxUsage>float</maxUsage>
            <minUsage>float</minUsage>
            <averageUsage>float</averageUsage>
    </resources>
    <resources id="Commerce">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
            <maxUsage>float</maxUsage>
            <minUsage>float</minUsage>
            <averageUsage>float</averageUsage>
    </resources>
</components>
```

EDIT: I need a JComboBox that show: House, Commerce, etc etc (the content of the id attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
List list = document.selectNodes("//resources/@id" ); //using xpath
Iterator iter=list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Attribute attribute=(Attribute)iter.next();
    jCombo.addItem(attribute.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Just follow this tutorial and you are good to go http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-dom4j/index.html